# Android Client Application (Possibly using ADB through USB)

Tags: java, android, usb, adb

Phone Information:
Droid Bionic
Android 2.3.4
USB Debugging Enabled

I am looking into writing an application for personal use, where I can send data from the client (on the phone) to the server application (on my computer), hopefully through USB. The only suggestions I have found for this using Android 2.3.4 is to use ADB and then to do something with TCP forwarding.

I have wrote a simple server and client application between computers using port 8001, but am having issues getting the client on my android to work with the server piece on my computer. I can create a socket for to talk to my computer (192.168.1.26, 8001), but can't seem to get it to work because the java is different on the android device from the comptuer client I made. Does anybody know of a very simple tutorial or example I can look at for just connecting the client to a server piece? All of the previous examples I have looked at are all complicated.

As for the USB portion, I would hopefully like to be able to get my application to work without going through the network. I have seen things about using "ADB forward tcp:port tcp:port", but am a bit confused on the whole thing. What do I set for the IP address and port number for the socket on the client, and do I leave the server on port 8001? What command do I use through ADB to do this if I wan't to use port 8001?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to forward TCP port 8001 on your computer to port 8001 on the phone, you'd use this command:

`adb forward tcp:8001 tcp:8001`

You can change the ports on either the phone or the device, if needed. Documentation for that command is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#forwardports

As for why this shouldn't work -- there's some information missing from your question. These are just standard TCP sockets. The Java version shouldn't make any difference, so I don't understand your problem. The client running on your computer could be written in any language (Ruby, C++, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

When I setup a socket on my phone, should i continue to use the 192.168.1.26 ip address then or does that not matter?

Comment: It will appear as a local socket on both devices. So, you should use 127.0.0.1 (the loopback address) on both ends. (Other IP addresses may work, depending on your firewall settings and how adb is configured to bind. However, you'll need to keep track of your IP address as it changes. Using 127.0.0.1 will always work.)

Answer (score 3):

I just finished working this out for an app that transfers the camera video feed from 2 android phones to my PC.

First run this on your PC:

```
adb devices
```

You should get something like this:

```
xxxyyy1    device
xxxyyy2    device
```

Make note of the xxxyyy1, and xxxyyy2 serial numbers given, then run these 2 commands:

```
adb -s xxxyyy1 forward tcp:8001 tcp:8002
adb -s xxxyyy2 forward tcp:8003 tcp:8004
```

These 2 port-forwards will only apply to the given device numbers so your PC can now communicate with the devices independently.